# How do you handle options that can't be used together (using OptionParser)?

Tags: python, optparse

My Python script (for todo lists) is started from the command line like this:

```
todo [options] <command> [command-options]
```

Some options can not be used together, for example

```
todo add --pos=3 --end "Ask Stackoverflow"
```

would specify both the third position and the end of the list. Likewise

```
todo list --brief --informative
```

would confuse my program about being brief or informative. Since I want to have quite a powerful option control, cases like these will be a bunch, and new ones will surely arise in the future. If a users passes a bad combination of options, I want to give an informative message, preferably along with the usage help provided by optparse. Currently I handle this with an if-else statement that I find really ugly and poor. My dream is to have something like this in my code:

```
parser.set_not_allowed(combination=["--pos", "--end"], 
                       message="--pos and --end can not be used together")
```

and the OptionParser would use this when parsing the options.

Since this doesn't exist as far as I know, I ask the SO community:
How do you handle this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possibly by extending `optparse.OptionParser`:

```
class Conflict(object):
    __slots__ = ("combination", "message", "parser")

    def __init__(self, combination, message, parser):
        self.combination = combination
        self.message = str(message)
        self.parser = parser

    def accepts(self, options):
        count = sum(1 for option in self.combination if hasattr(options, option))
        return count <= 1

class ConflictError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, conflict):
        self.conflict = conflict

    def __str__(self):
        return self.conflict.message

class MyOptionParser(optparse.OptionParser):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        optparse.OptionParser.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.conflicts = []

    def set_not_allowed(self, combination, message):
        self.conflicts.append(Conflict(combination, message, self))

    def parse_args(self, *args, **kwds):
        # Force-ignore the default values and parse the arguments first
        kwds2 = dict(kwds)
        kwds2["values"] = optparse.Values()
        options, _ = optparse.OptionParser.parse_args(self, *args, **kwds2)

        # Check for conflicts
        for conflict in self.conflicts:
            if not conflict.accepts(options):
                raise ConflictError(conflict)

        # Parse the arguments once again, now with defaults
        return optparse.OptionParser.parse_args(self, *args, **kwds)
```

You can then handle `ConflictError` where you call `parse_args`:

```
try:
    options, args = parser.parse_args()
except ConflictError as err:
    parser.error(err.message)
```

Comment: `super()` will not work for Python 2.X, as `OptionParser` is created as an old-style class. A solution is provided on [Stack Overflow question 2023940](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023940/using-super-when-subclassing-python-class-that-is-not-derived-from-objectold).

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed it by spelling out the superclass explicitly.

Comment: @Tamás: I don't think this solution actually works in practice, for several reasons.  First, `parser` is missing from the "slots" definition in the `Conflict` class, and I think the `parser.has_option()` call should be `self.parser.has_option()`.  More importantly, the `parser.has_option()` bit just checks if the parser has those options defined, not if those options were actually passed by the user.

Comment: @tonycpsu: thanks for the head up, I have fixed these problems now. I missed gotgenes's answer previously since I never came back to this question once I posted my answer. Hopefully the current version works properly.

Answer (score 3):

Tamás's answer is a good start, but I couldn't get it to work, as it has (or had) a number of bugs, including <strike>a broken call to super</strike>, `"parser"` missing in `Conflict.__slots__`, always raising an error when a conflict is specified because of the use of `parser.has_option()` in `Conflicts.accepts()`, etc.

Since I really needed this feature, I rolled my own solution and have made it available from the [Python Package Index](http://pypi.python.org/) as [ConflictsOptionParser](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ConflictsOptionParser). It works pretty much as a drop in replacement for [`optparse.OptionParser`](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html). (I do know [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html) is the new command line parsing hotness, but it is not available in Python 2.6 and below and has less adoption currently than `optparse`. Send me an email if you'd like to hack up or have hacked up an additional `argparse`-based solution.) The key is two new methods, `register_conflict()`, and, to a lesser extent, `unregister_conflict()`:

```
#/usr/bin/env python

import conflictsparse
parser = conflictsparse.ConflictsOptionParser("python %prog [OPTIONS] ARG")
# You can retain the Option instances for flexibility, in case you change
# option strings later
verbose_opt = parser.add_option('-v', '--verbose', action='store_true')
quiet_opt = parser.add_option('-q', '--quiet', action='store_true')
# Alternatively, you don't need to keep references to the instances;
# we can re-use the option strings later
parser.add_option('--no-output', action='store_true')
# Register the conflict. Specifying an error message is optional; the
# generic one that is generated will usually do.
parser.register_conflict((verbose_opt, quiet_opt, '--no-output'))
# Now we parse the arguments as we would with
# optparse.OptionParser.parse_args()
opts, args = parser.parse_args()
```

It has a few advantages over the solution begun by Támas:

- It works out of the box and is installable through [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) (or `easy_install`, if you must).
- Options in a conflict may be specified either by their option strings or by their `optparse.Option` instances, which helps with the DRY principle; if you use the instances, you can change the actual strings without worrying about breaking conflict code.
- It follows normal `optparse.OptionParser.parse_args()` behavior and automatically calls `optparse.OptionParser.error()` when it detects conflicting options in the command line arguments, rather than throwing the error directly. (This is both a feature and a bug; kind of a bug in `optparse`'s general design, but a feature for this package in that it is at least consistent with `optparse` behavior.)